# Azure ARM Template dependsOn: Resource Not Defined in Template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I want to create a new vm to resource group in azure with visual studio 2015.
the new vm depends on an existing resource in the same resource group , that isn’t declared in the template. but I got "The resource 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/***' is 
02:21:10 - not defined in the template"

```
"resources": [
{
  "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
  "name": "[variables('vmName')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "VirtualMachine"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('0abb7c58-93b4-45f4-b1be-61a98ac347a3','securitydata','Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccounts_simscitestrg6892_name'))]"
  ],
```

DependsOn can only refer to resources in the same ARM template ?

Any help appreciated.

Regards, Frank.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> DependsOn can only refer to resources in the same ARM template ?

From this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-define-dependencies) about defining dependencies in Azure Resource Manager templates, we could find as follows:

> Resource Manager evaluates the dependencies between resources, and deploys them in their dependent order. When resources are not dependent on each other, Resource Manager deploys them in parallel. **You only need to define dependencies for resources that are deployed in the same template**.

Based on my test, I could reproduce this issue. You need to add the Storage resource within your template as follows:

```html
{
    "name": "[parameters('storageAccounts_simscitestrg6892_name')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
    "dependsOn": [],
    "tags": {
      "displayName": "StorageAccountResourceName"
    },
    "properties": {
      "accountType": "[parameters('StorageAccountType')]"
    }
}
```

For your VM resource, you could configure the `osDisk` under the "properties > storageProfile" section as follows:

```html
"osDisk": {
  "name": "Your-VMOSDisk",
  "vhd": {
    "uri": "[concat('https://', parameters('storageAccounts_simscitestrg6892_name'), '.blob.core.windows.net/', variables('Your-VMStorageAccountContainerName'), '/', variables('Your-VMOSDiskName'), '.vhd')]"
  },
  "caching": "ReadWrite",
  "createOption": "FromImage"
}
```

The storage resource would be created under the same location as your VM, if not exists.

Comment: yes, I use reference function.                                                                  "outputs": {
    "storageAccountInfo": {
      "value": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('storageAccountname')),providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0])]",
      "type": "object"
    }
  }

Answer (score 3):

No, this makes no sense, the dependsOn property is meant to track dependencies inside the ARM template, so it can provision resources in specific order. If a resource is there, there's no sense to track it. It's already there. You just reference it when you use it.

Comment: yes, I use reference function.                                                                  "outputs": {
    "storageAccountInfo": {
      "value": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('storageAccountname')),providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0])]",
      "type": "object"
    }
  }

Comment: There is at least one case where this could actually make sense, as it seems that deployment is eventually consistent in ARM. Say I deploy resource B, dependent on resource A, both with a linked template, type `Microsoft.Resources/deployments`. A `dependsOn` is set from B to A. The point is that when the deployment of A is over it might be the case that the resources in B don't see those in A yet, causing the B deployment to fail. Having a look around quite a few people are complaining about this, I was not able to find a solution yet.

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing, and I have an example where it does not work - we might be filing an issue.

Comment: mmm, that shouldn't be possible. do you have a repro?

Comment: not true, there are many cases where a resource already exits outside the template but is required by microsoft documentation .e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-infrastructure-as-code?tabs=linux#app-service-plan says we need a dependent storage account. this might already exist outside the function deployement

Comment: but you don't need to dependsOn the resource, its not part of the template, its already there, please, I've been doing this for 7 years.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. DependsOn is used when you are creating a resources which depends on another resource which you are creating via the same template. If the resource is already created then you just add a reference to it. In your case, you can add properties key for the VM like this:

```
"properties": {
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "Standard_DS1"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "imageReference": {
                        "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServerHPCPack",
                        "offer": "WindowsServerHPCPack",
                        "sku": "2012R2",
                        "version": "latest"
                    },
                    "osDisk": {
                        "name": "[parameters('virtualMachines_APP01_name')]",
                        "createOption": "FromImage",
                        "vhd": {
                            "uri": "[concat('https', '://', parameters('storageAccounts_vmdkstorageacct_name'), '.blob.core.windows.net', concat('/vhds/', parameters('virtualMachines_APP01_name'),'APP01.vhd'))]"
                        },
                        "caching": "ReadWrite"
                    },
                    "dataDisks": []
                },
                "osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachines_APP01_name')]",
                    "adminUsername": "vmadmin",
                    "windowsConfiguration": {
                        "provisionVMAgent": true,
                        "enableAutomaticUpdates": true
                    },
                    "secrets": [],
                    "adminPassword": "[parameters('virtualMachines_APP01_adminPassword')]"
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaces_app01_name'))]"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
```

Comment: yes, I use reference function.                                                                  "outputs": {
    "storageAccountInfo": {
      "value": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('storageAccountname')),providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0])]",
      "type": "object"
    }
  }